# Let $0\,^{\circ}\mathrm{} < A < 45\,^{\circ}\mathrm{}$ . If $420(\tan A + \cot A) = 841$ then ﬁnd the value of $(116 \cos A − 58 \sin A)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Let $0\,^{\circ}\mathrm{} < A < 45\,^{\circ}\mathrm{}$. If $$420(\tan A + \cot A) = 841$$ then ﬁnd the value of $$(116 \cos A −
58 \sin A)$$

One way to solve this is by usual method , that is putting $\cot A = 1/\tan A$ in first equation then finding angle A and then calculating the answer.

But here I cannot do that because the quadratic equation will be very complicated ( 420 times two is 840 , just 1 less than 841) and secondly the angle A won't be simple angle and I'm not allowed to use any tables.

So how should I solve this? Any hints are appreciated.
(This is not class-homework , I'm solving sample questions for a competitive exam )

Comment: Recognize $58(2\cos A-\sin A)$. Try to manipulate this further to get to the tangent. Try to isolate terms that look like the original equation. Multiply the first equation by tangent: $$\frac{420}{\cos^2A}=841\tan A$$ and $$420=841\cos A \sin A$$ I'd continue from here.

Comment: @orion I did recognize that right after seeing the problem . I will try to do what you said and post if I get any difficulties , Thanks !

Comment: @orion I didn't get what you did ( After "Multiply the first equation by tangent:")

Comment: I used $1+\tan^2 x=\frac{1}{\cos^2 x}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe that as $\displaystyle0< A<45^\circ, 0<\tan A<\tan45^\circ=1$

So,we have $\displaystyle\tan A+\frac1{\tan A}=\frac{841}{420}$

$\displaystyle\iff420\tan^2A-841\tan A+420=0$

So, the discriminant will be $\displaystyle841^2-4\cdot420\cdot420=841^2-840^2=841+840=41^2$

Solve the Quadratic Equation for $\tan A$ to get  $\displaystyle\tan A=\frac{841\pm41}{420}$

Clearly, $\displaystyle\tan A=\frac{841+41}{2\cdot420}>1$

So, we need $\displaystyle\tan A=\frac{841-41}{2\cdot420}=\cdots$ as it  lies in our required range

Also, $\displaystyle\sin A>0, \cos A>0$

So, $\displaystyle\cos A=+\frac1{\sqrt{\sec^2A}}=+\frac1{\sqrt{1+\tan^2A}}$ and  $\displaystyle\tan A=\frac{\sin A}{\cos A}\iff\sin A=\tan A\cos A $

Comment: Thank you , but I think this is a tedious way to solve the question because solving that quadratic equation is tedious ( I'm not allowed to use computer or calculator ) and the answer will not be a simple angle ( I'm not allowed to use trignometric tables ) . Instead do you have an idea on how to convert $2\cos A-\sin A$ in terms of $\tan A$?

Comment: $\tan A+\frac1{\tan A}=\frac{841}{420} \iff420\tan^2A-841\tan A+240=0$

Comment: @AGoogler, please find the edited version

Comment: @zaarcis, you made a typo while rectifying me :)

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Ouch, yes. :)

Comment: Thank you @labbhattacharjee ! The equation was very easy to solve after all ! ( I thought I would need to calculate 841^2 , lol ) . But cos A is coming as irrational number , so how should I calculate $116\cos A -58\sin A$ exactly ( the answer is an integer) ?

Comment: We have $$\tan A=\frac{40}{41}\iff\frac{\sin A}{40}=\frac{\cos A}{41}=\sqrt{\frac1{40^2+41^2}}=+\frac1{\sqrt{3281}}$$ as both $\cos A,\sin A>0$

Comment: @AGoogler Notice that $b^2 - 4ac = (841)^2 - (4)(420)^2 = 841^2 - 840^2$. Then $(a+1)^2 - a^2 = 2a + 1$, therefore $841^2 - 840^2 = 1681$. Then recognize that $1681 = 41^2$.

Comment: @AlijahAhmed Wolfram alpha gives the answer as 44 , which is also the answer given in the answer-sheet.

Comment: @AGoogler - you are correct (I had previously incorrectly thought that the answer was not an integer). There is a typo in the answer for $\tan A$, it should be $\frac{40}{42}$ instead of $\frac{40}{41}$, which confused me initially - apart from that, everything looks good.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee - There's just a typo in your answer - $\tan A=\frac{40}{42}$. This leads to $$\frac{\sin A}{40}=\frac{\cos A}{42}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{40^2+42^2}}=+\frac{1}{58}$$

Comment: @AlijahAhmed, thanks

Comment: @labbhattacharjee - your welcome. +1 for the good answer, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

All MPA trig questions are meant to be solved using quadratics. That's why the give angle is smaller that 45.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think the answer belongs here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/732598/a-circle-is-inscribed-in-sector-of-another-bigger-circle-given-acircle-find-th Besides, which competition are you both giving?

Comment: Yep I scanned answer of that and while reading this posted this here. The competition is M. prakash academy qualification test. One of the hardest competition. Academy for IIT traning.