# A circle is inscribed in sector of another bigger circle.Given A(circle) find the A(triangle formed by the center and the endpoints of the sector).

Tags: geometry, circles

Consider sector of circle $MAB$.  $∠AMB = 120◦$.
A circle $S$ touches side $AM$, side $MB$ and arc $AB$ as shown in the ﬁgure.
Area of circle $S$ is $75π/(7 + 4√3)$ . Find $4√3$ times the area of $△AMB$.

[image: figure]

Here , I know the area of circle , so radius can be calculated. For triangle $AMB$ , it's area is equal to $1/2*AM^2*\sin 120$(degrees). So I just require the length of $AM$, that is the radius of sector.

$AM$ and $MB$ are tangents to the circle so that may be of some help? But I'm stuck here .

Any hints are apreciated . (This is not class-homework , I'm solving sample questions for a competitive exam )

Answer (score 2):

$$A_S=\frac{75\pi}{7+4\sqrt3}\implies R=5\sqrt{\frac3{7+4\sqrt3}}$$

Let now $\;K\;$ be the intersection point between the circle (with center $\;O\;$ ,say) and the radius $\;AM\;$, and form the $\;30-60-90\;$ straight-angle triangle $\;KOM\;$ ,so that

$$R=KO=\color{red}{\frac{\sqrt3}2}\,MO\implies MO=\color{red}{10}\sqrt{\frac1{7+4\sqrt3}}$$

so finally, the radius $\;r\;$ of the circular sector is

$$r=MO+R=\frac{5(\color{red}2+\sqrt3)}{\sqrt{7+4\sqrt3}}=\color{red}5\;\;\left(\text{because}\;\;(2+\sqrt3)^2=7+4\sqrt3\ldots\right)$$

Comment: How is the answer that you got is different from the answer that Alijah Ahmed got ( see below) ?

Comment: @AGoogler, I can't tell (I haven't even read the other answer) but mine was the first one...:) And even if it wasn't: I bet you know sometimes several pretty similar answers pop up almost at once. This usually happens with elementary questions, like yours.

Comment: No , not that. I mean that you got the radius of the sector as something irrational , while Alijah got it as equal to 5. Who's right? I can't find a flaw in either of you , so I'm confused . Can you take a look at his answer ?

Comment: Oh, I see @AGoogler. Well, let me check for some minutes.

Comment: @AGoogler, good you asked me that: it was a stupid mistake of mine. Thanks. I edited my answer and the edited parts are in red now. It all was that in fact $\;R=\frac{\sqrt3}2MO\;$ **and not** $\;R=\sqrt3 MO\;$ as I wrote. Forgot that $\;1/2\;$ factor.

Answer (score 1):

Denote the centre of the smaller (inscribed) circle as $C$, and let the circle touch tangent $AM$ at point $X$, as illustrated in the figure below.

[image]

We are given the area of the inscribed circle, which is $\frac{75\pi}{7+4\sqrt{3}}$. Thus we have 
$$\frac{75\pi}{7+4\sqrt{3}}=\pi R^2 \Rightarrow R= 5\sqrt{\frac{3}{7+4\sqrt{3}}}$$

Now the line $CM$ can be calculated using the right angled triangle $\triangle MXC$, where $\angle XMC=\frac{\pi}{3}$, $\angle CXM=\frac{\pi}{2}$ ($XM$ is tangent of circle), so that $\angle XCM=\frac{\pi}{6}$, and $CX=R$.

$$CM=\frac{CX}{\sin \frac{\pi}{3}}=\frac{2R}{\sqrt{3}}$$

The radius of the big circle which the sector is part of is 
$$AM=R+CM=\left(1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\right)R=\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}+2}{\sqrt{3}}\right)R$$

Substituting in the value of $R$, we have

$$AM=5\sqrt{\frac{3}{7+4\sqrt{3}}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}+2}{\sqrt{3}}\right)=5\sqrt{\frac{3(2+\sqrt{3})^2}{(7+4\sqrt{3})(3)}}=5\sqrt{\frac{3(7+4\sqrt{3})}{(7+4\sqrt{3})(3)}}=5$$

Thus the length of $AM$, which is the radius of the sector, is $5$.

Answer (score 1):

...............................................................................................................................................(30 characters limit)
[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow ! Have you solved all the questions ?

Comment: Maths 2013 - All. Maths 2012 - All. Maths 2011 - Q21 is remained as answer is not given in solutions. Q33 is wrong.                   Maths 2011 Sample - 45,47,52,53,54 As answers are not given.                         Maths 2010 - Q55 I didn't got it.Q 58 is wrong. Q67,69,70,73 ans not given.        Maths 2009 - Didn't got Q83. Q 87,93,94 no ans is given.           Maths 2008 - 95,97,a,b,98,99,100.             Maths 2007 - 104,107,108,109,110,112.                         Just two left from physics I think they are wrong And all from chemistry.

Comment: how much time on an average did it take you to solve one maths question? I'm fearing that I won't be able to complete the question paper in time .

Comment: 3-4 minutes average sometimes it take 6-7 minutes to solve questions like Q49 due to long calculations needed to solve it. What about you?

Comment: Got 55 and 21. I was reading on ray BC and AB instead of in ray BC and AB. Thanks to you I tried to solve them again.

Comment: can you help me to solve http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/665823/find-the-lcm-of-3-numbers-given-hcf-of-each-2.  I failed to understand André Nicolas answer.

Comment: Ajay , I take about 15-20 minuites to solve one geometry problem ! And still I can't solve many of them . Can you suggest me a good geometry book ? By the way I answered you LCM & HCF question.

Comment: Just read formulas from class 11 or 12 book. Challenge and thrill of precollege mathematics also helps a lot. Also you could read other RMO related books.

Comment: Mathematical Olympiad challenges and Indian National Mathematical Olympiad (Arihant) are best for geometry. In these type of papers try to apply very simple theorems. These questions are tricky and are just intended to test your application skill. That's why they seem so hard. Not like our usual school syllabi.